# Raise Parent event from the User Control in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have created Custom User control which i am using in my application Page(which is deployed at _layouts folder).

Here is my scenario.

I have a save button in my custom user control, when i click on that control i would like to execute a method in .aspx(which is layout page).  How can i acheive this ?  Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same problem. This works perfiectly in asp.net. But when i use the same thing in sharepoint, whenever i try to access public properties of user controls in sharepoint , it does not give me intellisense and then gives me build error if i just type the property..
any body help pls.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a SharePoint question but here you can find an answer:

[Calling a method in parent page from user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623136/calling-a-method-in-parent-page-from-user-control/623355#623355)

I never actually done this but by looking at code there is nothing special and it should work on SharePoint. Of course instead of `System.Web.UI.Page` you are using `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase`

Comment: Yes you are right, this is not a sharepoint question, but i am facing this issue in sharepoint. Well, i have used this in .net website, it was working.  I declared event, delegate in user control, and registered the usercontrol in application page, but i am not able to get the event in application page codebehind (for ex: usercontrol.event).  I am not able to see any property in application page code behind.  I dont know whats wrong .

Comment: only difference is you might have to manually register the delegate method to the click method of the button, in OnLoad. EDIT: Just noticed that the link there includes that.